# Looping multi-dimensional arrays in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, php-7.2

I've just upgraded to PHP 7.2 and I'm getting ***PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array*** for the line `$myarray[$ex][0] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];` in this old code...

```
                $ex=0;
                $z=0;
                while($oldarray[$z]['ID']){
                    if(0==$duplicatename or !$duplicatename){
                        $ex++;
                        $myarray[$ex][0] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];
                        /*...*/
                    }
                    $z++;
                }
```

I've read that the more recent versions of PHP have [backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php) so I changed the offending line to `$myarray[$ex]['ID'] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];` but I'm getting the same error.

The site this code is from is old so I was really expecting more problems than just this one piece of code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please.

Here is a var_dump of `$oldarray`, I've edited it slightly to change the content...

> array(4) { [0]=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> int(59480) ["boxid"]=> int(11158) ["galleryurl"]=> string(75) "http://..." ["gallerytitle"]=> string(63) "Gallery title goes here" ["gallerytype"]=> string(5) "photo" ["gallerydate"]=> int(1542544634) ["galleryactive"]=> string(1) "y" ["usersubmitted"]=> string(1) "n" ["userip"]=> NULL ["galleryhot"]=> string(1) "n" ["gallidentify"]=> int(372239531175) } [1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php)=> array(11) { ["ID"]=> int(59324) ["boxid"]=> int(11158) ["galleryurl"]=> string(79) "http://..." ["gallerytitle"]=> string(45) "Gallery title goes here" ["gallerytype"]=> string(5) "photo" ["gallerydate"]=> int(1538477012) ["galleryactive"]=> string(1) "y" ["usersubmitted"]=> string(1) "n" ["userip"]=> NULL ["galleryhot"]=> string(1) "n" ["gallidentify"]=> int(428341079414) } }

Comment: What does `$oldarray` look like? What does `$myarray` look like?

Comment: You can do an is_array() check to see if the elements are indeed arrays

Comment: @miken32 It's old code and it's not the best but $oldarray[integer]['string'] and $myarray is now an identical format to $oldarray.

Comment: `var_dump` it and edit your question to include that info. See more on a [mcve].

Comment: Also your error message will tell you exactly which line is causing this problem.

Comment: The exact line is the one I stated in the question `$myarray[$ex][0] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];` which I changed to `$myarray[$ex]['ID'] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];`. Which means that $myarray isn't getting created at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a possibility to refactor it with using of foreach?

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

What you will get if you will use:

```
print_r($oldarray);
print_r($myarray);
```

?

There is some probability you have object in second array dimension ... 
we need to see a bigger piece of code to help you effectively ...

What will happen if you will change:

```
$myarray[$ex][0] = $oldarray[$z]['ID'];
```

by this way:

```
$myarray[$ex][0] = $oldarray[$z].ID;
```

?

Comment: Try add: def $myarray = array(); on start of your code piece to ensure its declared in suitable way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks. I think using a `foreach` is probably the way to go. I'll play around with that now.

Comment: What will do similar way like this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#83388 ? Thanks for voting me up :)